# CSS - Applying a gradient to a sloped body

Tags: html, css

Is it possible to apply a vertical linear gradient to the resulting shape for html tag body using only CSS?
[image]

Thank you very much in advance..

Answer (score 2):

```css
    .grad2 {
        height: 100px;
        background: linear-gradient(135deg, rgba(18,18,18,1) 0%, rgba(28,28,28,1) 9%, rgba(43,43,43,1) 24%, rgba(18,18,18,1) 40%, rgba(0,0,0,1) 49%, rgba(43,43,43,1) 50%, rgba(71,71,71,1) 61%, rgba(102,102,102,1) 75%, rgba(89,89,89,1) 88%, rgba(77,77,77,1) 100%);
    }
```

```html
    <div class="grad2"></div>
```

Check this tool, it will help you very much: http://www.cssmatic.com/gradient-generator#

Comment: Hi, thank.. this is not a problem to do, The problem is that the lower right side must be the same color as the upper left side. top left color == botom left color. As shown in Figure.

Comment: you can easily do that by the link i gave you just move the circles to manipulate the gradient

i made this quickly it may be useful 
background: linear-gradient(135deg, rgba(76,76,76,1) 0%, rgba(44,44,44,1) 0%, rgba(0,0,0,1) 51%, rgba(71,71,71,1) 51%, rgba(89,89,89,1) 52%, rgba(43,43,43,1) 68%, rgba(28,28,28,1) 69%, rgba(17,17,17,1) 70%, rgba(102,102,102,1) 73%, rgba(17,17,17,1) 73%, rgba(19,19,19,1) 100%);
filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#4c4c4c', endColorstr='#131313', GradientType=1 );